# Execution strategy in GsonBuilder is not applied

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have the following example:

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    int a;
    B b;
    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(this);
    }

}
```

```
public class B implements Serializable {
    int c;
    byte[] d;
    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new BExclusionStrategy()).create();
        return gson.toJson(this);
    }

    public class BExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> arg0) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes attr) {
        return attr.getName().equals("d") && attr.getDeclaringClass() == B.class;
    }
    }
}
```

I want to exclude filed d when calling the `toString` method of class A, because the byte array is extremely long. But if i specify the execution strategy in class B it does not apply when calling `A.toString()`. But if I move the execution strategy to the `toString` method of class A it does work and field d is omitted.

Why is this so? Also class B is used in multiple different classes, and I want to omit printing d for all of them.

Why is this so? Also class B is used in multiple different classes, and I want to omit printing d for all of them.

Note: I don't want to use `transient byte[] d`, this would solve the printing issue though. I also tried @Exclude on the other fileds of class B and `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` but it also did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if i specify the execution strategy in class B it does not apply when calling `A.toString()`. But if I move the execution strategy to the `toString` method of class A it does work and field d is omitted.
>
> Why is this so?

Because when you call `A.toString()` which calls Gson, it uses reflection to serialize the fields of `A` and then `B`. Due to this `B.toString()` is never called and therefore your exclusion strategy specified there has no effect.

> I also tried @Exclude on the other fields of class B

Gson has no `@Exclude` annotation, it only has [`@Expose`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html). That `@Exclude` annotation might come from a different library, but Gson will just ignore it.

The easiest solution would be to use the `transient` field modifier. If you don't want to do that, then you could instead create a single Gson instance configured with your custom exclusion strategy which is then used by all of the `toString()` methods. You could also make the exclusion strategy more general by creating your own `@Exclude` annotation or similar and having the exclusion strategy check for that.

However, since your concern seems to be the length of the byte array `byte[] d`, you could alternatively use Gson's [`@JsonAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) annotation on that field to specify a custom adapter which creates a more concise JSON representation of the array.